# Writing functions inside classes in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to writing classes in Python and had a quick question. Here is some code below.

```
class Parse_profile():

  def __init__(self, page):
    self.page = page

  def get_title(self):
    list_of_titles = []
    for title in self.page.find_all(.....):
      list_of_titles.append(title.get_text())
    return list_of_titles

  def get_companies(self):
    list_of_companies = []
    for company in self.page.find_all(.....):
      list_of_companies.append(company)
    return list_of_companies
```

I want to create a third function that will take in both `list_of_companies` and `list_of_titles` (and more later on) and combine them into one list.

How do I do that?

Comment: `zip(list_of_titles,list_of_companies)` ?

Comment: Does this new function need information from the Parse_profile instance?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you want to combine them into a single list? Just add all the companies to the end of the list of titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_companies_and_titles(self):
    return self.get_companies() + self.get_title()
```

This will get you a list with all companies followed by all titles.
In case you want (company, title) tuples in your result-list, use:

```
def get_companies_and_titles(self):
    return zip(self.get_companies(), self.get_title())
```

The second option can yield unexpected results if the lists are not of the same length. Have a look at the documentation for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in that case.

Comment: I upvoted because this answers OP's question as stated... that said I am guessing this is not actually what OP meant :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley reading the question again it seems a litte ambiguous. Let's see if the author will clarify.

Comment: AHHH! Yes, this is what I was looking for. I was writing get_companies() inside the function and it was throwing an error. self.get_companies() works :-) Thank you!!

I wasn't sure how to pass a function into another function inside a class.

Comment: @MorganAllen no problem, happy coding.